# Show "Year" header row in FullCalendar resourceTimelineWeek view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, gantt-chart

I am using FullCalendar v6. I need to show Years in one header row and in another header row month name. Currently, it's showing single header row to show month name. Below is my code:

```
          <FullCalendar
            plugins={plugins}
            eventMinWidth={5}
            initialView='sixMonthView'
            daym
            views={
              {
                sixMonthView: {
                  eventOverlap: false,
                  type: 'resourceTimelineMonth',
                  duration: { months: 12},
                  slotLabelInterval: {months: 1},
                  slotDuration: { days: 1 },
                  dateIncrement: { months: 6 },
                  slotLabelClassNames: 'slot-label',
                  slotMinWidth: 120,
                },
  
              }
            }
            editable={true}
            selectable={true}
            selectMirror={true}
            dayMaxEvents={true}
            weekends={this.state.weekendsVisible}
            resources={[
              { id: 'a', title: 'Auditorium A' },
              { id: 'b', title: 'Auditorium B', eventColor: 'green' },
              { id: 'c', title: 'Auditorium C', eventColor: 'orange' },
            ]}
            // firstDay={6}
            initialDate={'2023-07-01'}
            initialEvents={[
              { title: 'nice', start: '2024-03-01', end: '2024-03-10', resourceId: 'a', allDay: true },
              { title: 'nice 2', start: '2024-03-01', end: '2024-03-10', resourceId: 'a', allDay: true }
            ]}
          />
```

Below is the screenshot of my expectation

[image]

But I am getting the following output:

[image]

Comment: Have you read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotLabelFormat yet?